# How can I have varied KMOD status' for a single key in Pygame?

Tags: events, key, pygame, modifiers

Here's what I've got so far:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            mods = pygame.key.get_mods()
            if mods and KMOD_SHIFT:
                movei = -5
            if mods and KMOD_CTRL:
                movei = -20
            else:
                movei = -10
```

The problem is it seems to only pick up one or the other (KMOD_SHIFT or KMDO_CTRL) ALL THE TIME, not selectively. So it doesn't matter which modifier I press (shift, alt, ctrl etc.) the effect is still the same.

The effect I'm going for is that the onscreen character can creep, run or walk, respectively.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the **logical** `and` operator, while you really need the **bit-wise** operator `&`. Instead of

```
if mods and KMOD_SHIFT:
```

you want

```
if mods & KMOD_SHIFT:
```

The logical `and` will return the value of the second operand as long as the first one has a true value (in this case, not equal to 0). The `&` operator will perform a bit-wise AND operation and will therefore return a non-zero value (logically interpreted as true) only if some of the bits from the KMOD constant are on in the `mods` variable.